I am not able to delete the docker container, i started to delete it but the status showing rendering about from 30 min
I am not able to delete the docker container. i started to delete it but the status showing rendering about from 30 min. i think its in deleting in progress, but taking too much of time. how can i delete it?
also this container does not start

I want to delete docker container.

You can check several things to solve your problem:
check docker status:
docker ps

force to remove container:
docker rm -f <container_id>

restart docker service
systemctl restart docker

also check your disk space:
df -h

